# What't the best structure for two AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a blog-style app on AnguarJS. It normally has two parts. One part is the admin pages for editing post, the other part is the view page for showing post to normal user (maybe also apply the page theme).

Now I have finished the amdin pages which are used to edit post. I am facing a design structure problem when planning the post view page.

My AppController is in the index page for admin pages, the page layout are also designed for admin page. The navigation bar and menus should not available to normal user (if they are not logged in as editor).

I can put them together and show/hide the admin part layout by checking login cookie or something. but the JavaScript files for admin pages are actually not needed for "view" post.

Should I separate them into two app? or I should put them together but use a static page to navigate them into different configuration?

What's the best design structure in this case?

P.S. I am using AngularJS and all the files are static file for now. Will involve Express if necessary.

Update: The reason I want to separate them into two parts is that the post will be viewed on mobile phone in most of the case. It will save some data traffic for user if admin code won't be loaded in post view page.

Comment: two separate app modules make sense

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it doesn't really matter, and makes very little difference.

If you use a [router](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), then you can design a view for `yoursite/admin/` that is completely different to `yoursite/post/:id`. Alternatively, you could split the site into two different modules and create two different 'apps'.

The main difference, and the only one that would be noticeable to the user, is that there would be a page load when switching from admin to viewer and vice versa if you take the two-app approach.

My preference (and the approach I consider to be the 'angular way') is to use a router to change the view to make the experience smoother.

Comment: To make the experience smoother is not relevant IMO because lambda users shouldn't use the admin.

Comment: Why is the admin experience not relevant though?

Comment: I didn't mean to say admin experience is not relevant. But switching from admin mode to normal mode is not as important as having a normal mode (most users) being smooth. And freeing the normal mode from loading admin code makes normal mode smoother.

Comment: I agree that normal being smooth is a priority, but I disagree that it will be noticeably smoother by not loading the admin code unless you're using a 486 without the turbo button pressed.

Comment: The admin code can include a whole lot of things, especially for post edition: RTEs usually weight a lot.

Comment: Thank you Ed Hinchliffe. I am using $routeProvider to route the url and all the files are static. The reason I want to separate them into two parts is that the post will be viewed on mobile in most of the case. So if the post view page doesn't have the admin JavaScript, it can save some data traffic for user.